# EKEvent created programmatically, fetch EKEvent from iPhones calendar, identify both (EKEvents)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, eventkit, ekeventstore

EKEvent created from my App programmatically, when i fetch EKEvent create in iPhone calendar, how i can identify both (EKEvent) events which is created by  iPhone calendar or by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things you can do .
1.Create your own calendar .
2.Add extra text in the Notes field . while fetching check notes field and sort them .

Eventkit doesnt support that kind of sortinh in app or outside app .